# About notations of spectral measure

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

I saw the lecture notes [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2006/PAPERS/RaskinSam.pdf). It says that For compact spectral measure $E$, there exists unique normal operator $A$, s.t. $\int \lambda d(E_{\lambda}v|w)$, for abbreviation we write as $A = \int \lambda d E_{\lambda}$. Here $E_{\lambda} = E(\lambda)$.

So can we say that $Av = (\int \lambda dE_{\lambda})v = \int \lambda v dE_{\lambda} = \int \lambda d(E_{\lambda}v)$ ?

Also, if spectrum $\sigma(A)$ is discrete, why $\int_{\sigma(A)} \lambda d(E_{\lambda}v|w)$ over discrete set can be nonzero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example ... Start with a complete orthonormal subset $\{ e_{n} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Let $\{\lambda_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. You can define a bounded self-adjoint operator $T$ by
$$
                  Tx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n \langle x,e_n\rangle e_n
$$
Every $\lambda_n$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, with $Te_n=\lambda_n e_n$. The associated spectral measure is
$$
            E(S)x = \sum_{\{ n : \lambda_n \in S \}}\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n
$$
Because $\{ e_n \}$ is a complete orthonormal subset of $\mathcal{H}$, then $E(\mathbb{R})$ is the identity operator $I$. The operator $T$ may be written as $Tx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lambda dE(\lambda)x$, which is the typical and somewhat misleading notation used to denote a general integral because $E$ is not a function of a real variable $\lambda$. Using this notation, the integral represents a sum:
$$
                 Tx=\int \lambda dE(\lambda)x = \sum_{n}\lambda_n\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n
$$
The completeness of the orthonormal subset $\{ e_n\}$ is expressed by
$$
                     x = \int dE(\lambda)x = \sum_{n}\langle x,e_n\rangle e_n.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I feel it seems it should be defined as $\langle E(S)u, v\rangle = \int \lambda d\langle E(\lambda)u, v\rangle$. Using $d\langle E(\lambda)u, v\rangle$ as scalar measure seems more intuitive than $dE(\lambda)x$ which is vector-valued measure. I feel difficult to understand what $dE(\lambda)x$ vector-valued measure actually means.
Besides, can we just say that $\int_{\lambda_n} \lambda dE(\lambda)x = \lambda_n \langle x, e_n\rangle e_n$? Is integration at a single point well-defined?

Comment: @threeautumn yes, the notation is awkward, even for Lebesgue measure where you write $\int f(x)dm(x)$, but you don't really mean $m$ depends on a variable. For $E$, the argument is really a set, as it is for any measure.